# How to surpress audit daemon rotating log messages?

Tags: centos, rhel, logs, systemd-journald

On a CentOS 7 system messages like these are logged several times a day:

```
Sep 24 00:11:42 example.org auditd[756]: Audit daemon rotating log files
Sep 24 00:26:23 example.org auditd[756]: Audit daemon rotating log files
```

(they show up e.g. when executing `journalctl -fa`)

Well, I don't really see the point in those messages. I mean, exactly how it is important that auditd is reporting that it is (again and regularly) rotating its log files.

Thus my question how to disable those kind of log messages.

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box, auditd rotates after 6 MiB are written to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Thus, when auditd issues its rotate log messages to often, it may be a sign that an unusual amount of audit log messages are produced.

Then it is likely that a SELinux policy is missing or needs to be extended (cf. audit2why/audit2allow). Another cause can be mis-labeled files (cf. restorecon).

Alternatively, the amount of audit logs may also be caused by normal activity, just because it is a busy system. In that case it may make sense to increase the rotate size limit in (`/etc/audit/auditd.conf`).

Beside that, auditd logs those message with syslog severity 'NOTICE' - i.e. they do not turn up in `journalctl` output when matching only higher levels. But be aware that auditd also uses severity NOTICE for more serious messages (including some error conditions).